# Storing data in the app sandbox - what if the user runs out of space?

Tags: iphone

I am storing some images locally in my app's sandbox. I currently have the minimum set at 10MB, and will be allowing the user to choose how much storage is allowed (up to 500MB).

In the scenario that the app is installed on a device where there's simple no space on it, or if there's 1MB space left and I start saving a 2MB image what happens?

Comment: Did any answer help you? Just click the check mark to mark it as an accepted solution or vote it up. And please check your other questions for possible solutions, too. Thanks! :)   (And yes, this is copy-pasted so new users are aware of the voting system.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your save method will fail and throw an `NSFileWriteOutOfSpaceError`.

If you handling a lot of disk space [this might useful to you](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/device-information/how-to-obtain-total-and-available-disk-space-on-your-iphone-or-ipod-touch).

Edit:
To the space left, you can use this code:

```
NSDictionary *fsAttr = [ [NSFileManager defaultManager] fileSystemAttributesAtPath:NSTemporaryDirectory()]; 
NSNumber *totalFreeSize = [fsAttr objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize];
```

Comment: Thanks. However, this gets me the total disk space on the device, not what's left.